# Do the difficulties in generalising Henstock-Kurzweil still exist if every subset of $\mathbb R^n$ is Lebesgue measurable?

Tags: integration, axiom-of-choice

There are apparently some difficulties generalising the Henstock-Kurzweil integral from functions of signature $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ to functions of signature $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$. One desirable property of such a generalisation would be a simple formulation of the Divergence Theorem, as well as a Fubini theorem. Would these difficulties still exist if we assumed the negation of the Axiom of Choice, and assumed instead the axiom that all subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ are Lebesgue measurable?

This builds on this question: [What are the obstructions for a Henstock-Kurzweil integral in more than one dimension?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34077/what-are-the-obstructions-for-a-henstock-kurzweil-integral-in-more-than-one-dime)

See also the [Wikipedia entry on the Solovay model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solovay_model) and the [entry on dream mathematics](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dream+mathematics) at nLab.